# Scope and Namespace routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise, namespaces, doorkeeper

I'm following a tutorial on **Dookeeper** and **Devise** gems in Rails, in one point of the video, the author creates the following routes:

```
namespace :api do
 namespace :v1 do
  resources:books
 end
end

scope :api do
 scope :v1 do
  use doorkeeper do
    skip_controllers:authorizations,:applications,:authorized_applications
   end
  end
end
```

I don't quite understand what's the point of the namespace and scope in point... They complement each other or are separated things and why do I have to use?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a helpful overview](https://devblast.com/b/rails-5-routes-scope-vs-namespace).

In short (my emphasis added):

> When you use `namespace`, it will prefix the URL path for the specified resources, **and try to locate the controller under a module named in the same manner as the namespace**.

> When using `scope` without any options and only a scope name, it will **just change the resources path**.

So `scope` is useful for making a route match `namespace` when there aren't controllers with matching names.

```rb
namespace :api do
 namespace :v1 do
  resources:books
 end
end
```

Gives you a base route of "/api/v1/books" but requires a `Api::V1::BooksController`

```rb
scope :api do
 scope :v1 do
  use doorkeeper do
    skip_controllers:authorizations,:applications,:authorized_applications
   end
  end
end
```

Gives doorkeeper routes that start with "api/v1" but without trying to match to an `Api::V1::Doorkeeper` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chiperific! I get it now!